# Build error message when running SVNPoller

Tags: buildbot

I'm trying to setup Buildbot in my organization but have a problem with the SVNPoller.

Whenever the subversion repository changes the SVNPoller correctly keeps recognizes this but then fails with the following errors message:

**SVNPoller failed [Failure instance: Traceback: : changes.project may not be NULL**

I'm pretty sure that I made a mistake but this error message just doesn't really help, so any help is appreciated.

**master.cfg:**

---

```
svn_poller = SVNPoller(
                    svnurl=source_code_svn_url,
                    pollinterval=60*10, # seconds
                    svnuser='job_guest',
                    svnpasswd='job_guest',
                    svnbin='/usr/bin/svn'
)
c['change_source'] = [ svn_poller ]
```

**twistd.log**

---

```
2010-11-11 14:24:01+0100 [-] SVNPoller polling
2010-11-11 14:24:03+0100 [-] svnPoller: _process_changes 34177 .. 34178
2010-11-11 14:24:03+0100 [-] Adding change revision 34178
2010-11-11 14:24:03+0100 [-] adding change, who doberkofler, 1 files, rev=34178, branch=None, repository=http://10.43.1.11/svn/job/ljs_app/trunk, comments test, category None, project None
2010-11-11 14:24:03+0100 [-] SVNPoller failed [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'pysqlite2.dbapi2.IntegrityError'>: changes.project may not be NULL
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:312:_startRunCallbacks
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:328:_runCallbacks
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:289:_continue
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:285:unpause
            --- <exception caught here> ---
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:328:_runCallbacks
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/changes/svnpoller.py:504:submit_changes
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/changes/manager.py:114:addChange
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/master.py:1146:addChange
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/db/connector.py:308:addChangeToDatabase
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/db/connector.py:212:runInteractionNow
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/db/connector.py:237:_runInteractionNow
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/db/connector.py:326:_txn_addChangeToDatabase
            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/buildbot/db/dbspec.py:105:execute
            ]
2010-11-11 14:34:01+0100 [-] SVNPoller polling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused the error: when using SVNPoller it is imeperative to also set the project parameter!

```
svn_poller = SVNPoller(
                    project='project',        
                    svnurl=source_code_svn_url,
                    pollinterval=60*10, # seconds
                    svnuser='job_guest',
                    svnpasswd='job_guest',
                    svnbin='/usr/bin/svn'
)
c['change_source'] = [ svn_poller ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if you are using 0.8 or higher, they require you to specify a project even if you don't want to; since there is no default.

Just add the `project = 'myproject'` in the poller, as the other user suggested too, and you should be good to go.